# Parsing "NA" entries as NaN values when reading in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

i am new to pandas. I have loaded csv using pandas.read_csv. i have tried not to specify dtype but it was way too slow. since it is a very large file, i also specified data type. however, sometimes in numeric columns, it contains "NA".  i have used na_values = ['NA'], will it affect my data frame? i still want to preserve these rows. my question is if i specify data type and add na_values = ['NA'], will NA be tossed away? if yes, how can i maintain similar process time without losing these na? thank you very much!

Comment: `NA` will be parsed to `NaN` (`np.nan`) when your dataset is loaded.

Comment: You couldn't test this out yourself?

Comment: i did a isnull check later and didnt find any. so i was confused. i'll test again.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) docs:

> `na_values` : scalar, `str`, `list`-like, or `dict`, default `None`
>
> Additional
>   strings to recognize as `NA`/`NaN`. If `dict` passed, specific per-column NA
>   values. By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’,
>   ... **‘NA’**, ...`.

Bold emphasis mine. These values are not tossed away, rather, they are converted to `NaN`. Pandas is smart enough to automatically recognise those values without you explicitly stating it.